# svn stuck because disk quota exceeded

Tags: svn, version-control

I was trying to update my svn repository in my remote computer but the update was not completed since the disk quota was exceeded. Svn then said I had to do a cleanup and upon typing svn cleanup, I get the message:

Can't close file '.../.svn/tmp/svn-a9xwCi': Disk quota exceeded.

I want to do the following:

1. undo the update. How do I do this? I can't even type 'svn log', svn says I need to run cleanup (again).
2. Is there a way that I update some parts of my repo? There are some data files in my repo that take up some space and I don't need these data files in my repo for my remote computer. The data files are all in one folder. How do I exclude this folder from the update?

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear some space first (or increase your quota), so that you have enough space for the svn cleanup.